# Perl Strange Buffered Output Behavior

Tags: perl, io

I've recently been trying to teach myself Perl and have been doing some basic exercises. In one of them, you have a hard-coded hash of last names to first names. The user inputs a last name and you output the first name -- relatively straightforward. The code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

my %first_name = (
    Doe => 'John',
    Johnson => 'Bob',
    Pitt => 'Brad',
);

print "What is your last name?\n";
chomp (my $last_name = <STDIN>);
print "Your first name is $first_name{$last_name}.\n";
```

Now, something strange happens. The **"What is your last name?\n"** line is not displayed until I input something to the program (and press Enter), after which, the following is printed:

```
What is your last name?
Your first name is .
Use of uninitialized value within %first_name in concatenation (.) or string at     test.pl line 14, <STDIN> line 1.
```

Now, I understand the notion of buffered output and all that, and, if I add `$| = 1` at the beginning of my program, it works. However, my expectation would be that even without that line, even though `print` statement strings might not print immediately, my input string will still be placed in the `$last_name` variable, which it is not. So, I have two questions regarding this:

1. Why is this happening? Is it an OS thing (I'm running on Windows)?
2. Why is it that adding a `\n` does not flush the output (as various sources say it does)?

**Note:** If I replace the last line that accesses the `%first_name` hash with a simple printing of the `$last_name` variable, then, even though the output is still "delayed", the variable has the correct value.

**Note #2**: Alternatively, if the code after printing the last name is replaced with this,

```
if (exists $first_name{$last_name}){ 
   print "Your first name is $first_name{$last_name}.\n";
}

else{
    print "Last name is not in hash.\n";
}
```

then `$last_name` does get assigned the correct value from `<STDIN>`. I am not sure what to make of this.

Comment: It works fine on my Mac, so I think it's a Windows issue.

Comment: what flavour of perl are you using on Windows?

Comment: and in what kind of environment?  just a windows cmd window?

Comment: I tried it both with a regular command-line running `perl.exe` and with Komodo IDE. Both give the same results.

Comment: My thumbs have a strange UTF pricking.

Comment: Yeah, this works dandy for me on ActivePerl for Windows.  I kind of suspect your character encoding.  I'd be interested in seeing what `use Encode qw(encode); print encode('utf8', 'Doe');` or `print encode('utf8', $last_name);` produce.

Comment: Interestengly enough, I used `UTF-8` and it worked. However, I removed `UTF-8` after that and it still worked. I think those lines somehow "reset" the behavior. How strange -- but thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not checking in your program whether the last name is in the hash or not, if it is not then you should display some message like "$lastname not found".

By the way your program is working fine on my side if I enter the correct lastname (which exists in the hash).

So you may edit your program like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %first_name = (
    Doe => 'John',
    Johnson => 'Bob',
    Pitt => 'Brad',
);

print "What is your last name?\n";
chomp (my $last_name = <STDIN>);

# Check if the last_name exists in hash or not
if (exists $first_name{$last_name}){ 
   print "Your first name is $first_name{$last_name}.\n";
}

# If it doesn't then show a custom message
else{
    print "not found";
}
```

Perhaps you are [suffering from buffering](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html).

Comment: Yup, I omitted the check because it was not important for this example. However, the problem still persists that the `$last_name` variable is not assigned the value from `<STDIN>`. I am not certain that this is just a Windows issue (more likely something subtle in my code?) -- I'm using ActivePerl, and, if such a strange and confusing behavior was due to Windows, at least one of the other 3 devs who are using Perl for Windows would have complained :)

Comment: `$| = 1` will solve the issue but I don't get why isn't it working without it.

Comment: hmm .. that doesn't solve it ... the problem is a mix of output buffering and not receiving the correct input. Check out my **Note:** in the original question.

Comment: I noticed that if you use the code which I have written then you will not face the issue, try it and let me know.

Comment: Yes, I just edited the question to include this. Thanks. It also seems to have fixed my problem!